# Liferay 6 : How to display all our developed Portlets page once the user logs in?

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay 6 for developing Portlets .
My question is , on liferay startup i am showing my Custom Login page  and once the user Logs in successfully i want to display  /redirect user our developed 6 Portlets

Please tell me how to achieve this ?? Or the concept name to achive this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new liferay page e.g. `.../web/guest/start` and put your 6 portlets to this page.
Then configure the start page in portal-ext.properties

```
default.guest.public.layout.friendly.url = /start
```

Comment: Logged into account test@liferay.com 

Then Navigate to Control Panel. 

Selected Page Templates from the left side list availabe under "liferay.com" section.

Clicked on Add Button , Created a New Page named Kiran .

Gave it all the Permissions , Opened that Page Template , and when i tried to Add my  Portlets to that Kiran Page , it displayed 

Configure this application and place it where desired on the page.

Please let me know what is this ??